# No newlines in stacktrace when run from command line?

Tags: java, command-line, log4j2

When i run my application from the command line (standard windows 7) the stacktraces put in my log file don't have newlines.

(hmm, i wanted to paste an example, but when i copy the stacktrace from my log in notepad and paste it in my browser, the newlines suddenly appear)

I also tried opening log with editplus editor but no luck either, stacktraces don't have newlines (enters).

My pattern layout is quite standard (log4j2):

```
<PatternLayout>
<Pattern>%d [%15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{3} %10X{username} - %m%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

I simply start my application jar (runnable jar)

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

When i run my application from eclipse the stacktraces in log do have newlines/enters.

Anybody got an idea where the problem may lie?

[edit]
The hex of 4 characters, first character on line 1 and last character on line 2.

```
74 0A 09 61
```

Which is:

```
T - something that isn't a newline? - tab? - A
```

[edit] A simple example with no dependencies except log4j2:

```
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

public class App {
    private org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log= org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
    public App() {  
        log.error("0", new SocketTimeoutException("test"));
        log.debug("starting");
        log.debug("starting2");
        log.debug("starting3");
        log.debug("starting4");
        log.debug("starting5");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{3} %10X{username} - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RandomAccessFile name="MyFile" fileName="client.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{3} %10X{username} - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.tate.world" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
        </Logger>


        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Create a runnable jar and run it from the command line:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

Now open the client.log with notepad, the SocketTimeoutException stacktrace has no newlines.

This is my manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . app_lib/log4j-api-2.4.1.jar ap
 p_lib/log4j-core-2.4.1.jar
Main-Class: com.tate.world.test.App
```

(i also tried the latest 2.5)
How can i get newlines (that show up in notepad) in the stacktrace?

Thanks for reading!

[edit] For something really weird, comment out the:

```
log.debug("starting2");
log.debug("starting3");
log.debug("starting4");
log.debug("starting5");
```

and run again from command line, now the stacktrace has newlines again!

Comment: Do you mean that all your logs are appended to the same line ?

Comment: @Berger yes, but only the stacktraces, the other log statements all have their own line.

Comment: The problem isn't your logger, the problem is that the code part which formats the stacktrace uses plain `\n` without caring about the current os.

Comment: @Tom thats what I was also thinking. TinusTate Try using a different program to view the logs.  Your porblem is probably the same as this one: http://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks

Comment: @Tom i don't do anything special with the stacktrade. I do have an UncaughtExceptionHandler which has log.error("Uncaught exception", t) (where t is a Throwable), this stacktrace doesn't have newlines in the log file. After that the handler converts the exception stacktrace to string with printStackTrace(printWriter) and sends it to server. Weird, when i throw a RuntimeException manually the stacktrace appears with newlines in the log. I'm going to do a bit more searching...

Comment: *"i don't do anything special with the stacktrade."* And I don't think that it is your fault here. Looks more like a core class or a library is doing something wrong. You could start with trying to find out, where the stacktrace is created/formatted. You could also spent your time on more important stuff and use a text editor which is capable of understandin `\n`. I can suggest Notepad++.

Comment: @Tom i wish it was that easy to just ignore it ;-) I installed notepad++ and stacktrace do show with newlines there. After a lot of system.exit(1) and log.error: the newlines in stacktraces disappear when a class is accessed that is inside one of my own jars (in my /lib/ folder). I'm going to turn that library inside out...

Comment: Good luck. Don't forget that you can write an answer when you found and solved the problem. Future readers with the same problem (and library) will appreciate that.

Comment: @Tom it seems it is log4j that causes the newline problem, I've added a example to my original post which is a simple test application with no other dependencies. After the example is run from the command line the stacktrace in the client.log won't have any newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the default printing of an stacktrace is bugged in log4j2, there's a bug report created in jan 2015:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-939

It's no biggy.

Lucky the solution is easy, just include exception in the pattern and the default printing is overridden by a printer that does handle newlines the correct way.